# How virtual memory looks like when a process is created [Windows]?

Tags: windows, memory, process, virtual-memory, low-level

Someone asked me this question a few days ago, and I couldn't find in the internet a detailed image, showing how the virtual memory looks like when a process is being created.

Let's say the process "program.exe" has been created.

How would you describe the memory layout, using the embedded image?

Can you please show and describe where is the "program.exe" itself in this layout, where are the imported DLLs, where is the heap, the stack, what's going on in the kernel, and etc.

I'll be glad for as much detailed image as you can.

---

Clear memory layout:

[image: Memory layout]
Partially filled memory layout (order doesn't really matter):

[image: Partially filled memory layout]

Comment: Start Program.exe and look with VMMap at its layout. That will give you the visual impression of it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap. It will  only show the user space of it because that is what the application will see since it is dealing with a Virtual Address Space which is virtualized by the OS for every application to isolate memory between processes.

Comment: Thanks @AloisKraus. It doesn't answer my questions since it's not in the visual form I look for, and of course lacks of Kernel space. Can you try maybe using the questioned image in your answer?

Comment: i be say question is unclear. what you mean under *where* ? exe, dll(s), heap, stack - all in user mode space.

Comment: @RbMm Yes but in which order? For example, the process and the DLLs are both in memory, but in different places. Ntdll.dll is in memory also. Kernel32.dll is there either. What else is there? Where would you place the Stack and the Heap in each process in memory?
It was basically an open question to see how could I present the virtual memory in visual..

Comment: @Moses - first mapped *exe* and *ntdll.dll* to process (of course first thread stack, teb, peb, etc) than loaded additional dlls.. anyway your question still unclear for me

Comment: @Moses: Look at the screenshot of the link to see how the memory looks like in user mode. What you are asking is how process creation is working. See Book Windows Internals or https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233328&seqNum=3 for a first glimpse how this really works.

Comment: There is no single heap location. Unlike Unix, a Windows process can and typically does have multiple heaps, and a heap can even be layered over shared memory (via the native NT API). Also, every thread has its own stack, typically growable with a reserved size that gets committed as required.

Comment: @AloisKraus That's a great resource.
I've updated the question to maybe deliver the question's idea more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following diagram from [this article](https://www.securitysift.com/windows-exploit-development-part-1-basics/):
[image: process memory layout]

The kernel memory is not related to the new process.

In contrast to user space memory, where each process has its own mapping, kernel space memory has only one mapping. When a thread runs in kernel mode it always sees the same address space, regardless of the process it belongs to.